# Using super and toString to update JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea, super

I am trying to use toString in the Person class to append the JTextArea in the EmployeesApplet class. Eventually the output is going to look like this [image: final output]

For the Person class it needs instance variables that are private, one constructor and a toString method, right now I'm just trying to get it to display the name so I can figure out how to do the rest
How would i finish my Person class?

The EmployeesApplet is below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class EmployeesApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener 
{
  public JButton              sd   = new JButton ("Salaried");
  public JButton              hr   = new JButton ("Hourly");
  public JButton              cm   = new JButton ("Commissioned");
  public JButton              cl   = new JButton ("Clear"); 

  private final int    FIELDS      =  8,   
                       FIELD_WIDTH = 20;   

  private String[]     strings     = new String[FIELDS];
  private TextFieldWithLabel[] tf  = new TextFieldWithLabel[FIELDS];
  private JTextArea    ta          = new JTextArea(5,25); 

  String[]  s = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Employee ID", "(a) Salaried: Weekly Salary", "(b1) Hourly 1: Rate Per Hour", 
                   "(b2) Hourly 2: Hours Worked" , "(c1) Commissioned: Rate", "(c2) Commissioned: Gross Sales" };

     public void init()
     {
      this.setSize(420, 310);

       //----------------------
       //  Set up the Structure
       //----------------------

       Container c = getContentPane();
       JPanel f   = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
       JPanel b   = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,0));

       JPanel glb = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,1,0,2));
       JPanel gtf = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,1,0,2));
       JPanel flb = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());


       // Add FlowLayout to the container
       c.add(f);
       // Add BorderLayout to the FlowLayout
       f.add(b);

       //---------------------------------------
       //Add JPanels to the BorderLayout regions
       //---------------------------------------

       // Add JLables to GridLayout in West
       b.add(glb, BorderLayout.WEST);
       for (int i = 0; i < tf.length; i++)
       {
        tf[i] = new TextFieldWithLabel(s[i], FIELD_WIDTH);
        glb.add(tf[i].getLabel());
       }

       // Add JTextFeilds to GridLayout in East
       b.add(gtf, BorderLayout.EAST);
       for (int i = 0; i < tf.length; i++)
       {
        tf[i] = new TextFieldWithLabel(s[i], FIELD_WIDTH);
        tf[i].getTextField();
        gtf.add(tf[i].getTextField());
       }

       // Add JButtons to FlowLayout in South
       b.add(flb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

       flb.add(sd);
       flb.add(hr);
       flb.add(cm);
       flb.add(cl);

       sd.addActionListener(this);
       hr.addActionListener(this);
       cm.addActionListener(this);
       cl.addActionListener(this);

       // Add JTextArea and make it not editable   
       f.add(ta);
       ta.setEditable(false);

     }

     //---------------------------------------
     //  Read all the JTextFields and 
     //  save the contents in a parallel array
     //---------------------------------------
     private void readFields()
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < tf.length; i++)  // or FIELDS
         strings[i] = tf[i].getText();
     }

     private boolean fieldsExist(int i, int i2)
     {
       if(i == 0 && i2 == 3)  // Checks Salaried worker
       {
         if(tf[0].getText()  == null || tf[0].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("First Name field is empty");  //  Diplays error message in status area
           tf[0].getTextField().requestFocus();  //  Places focus in JTextField
           return false;
         }
         else if(tf[1].getText()  == null || tf[1].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("Last Name field is empty");  
           tf[1].getTextField().requestFocus();  
           return false;
         }
         else if(tf[2].getText()  == null || tf[2].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("Employee ID field is empty"); 
           tf[2].getTextField().requestFocus(); 
           return false;
         }
         else if(tf[3].getText()  == null || tf[3].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("(a)Salried: Weekly Salary field is empty"); 
           tf[3].getTextField().requestFocus(); 
           return false;
         }       
         else        
         return true;
       }

       if(i == 0 && i2 == 2)  // Checks Hourly worker
       {
         if(tf[0].getText()  == null || tf[0].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("First Name field is empty");  
           tf[0].getTextField().requestFocus();  
           return false;
         }
         else if(tf[1].getText()  == null || tf[1].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("Last Name field is empty");  
           tf[1].getTextField().requestFocus();  
           return false;
         }
         else if(tf[2].getText()  == null || tf[2].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("Employee ID field is empty"); 
           tf[2].getTextField().requestFocus(); 
           return false;
         }
         else        
         return true;
       }

       if(i == 4 && i2 == 5)  // Checks Hourly worker the second time
       {
         if(tf[4].getText()  == null || tf[4].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("(b1) Hourly 1: Rate Per Hour field is empty");  
           tf[5].getTextField().requestFocus(); 
           return false;
         }
         else if(tf[5].getText()  == null || tf[5].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("(b2) Hourly 2: Hours Worked field is empty");  
           tf[5].getTextField().requestFocus();  
           return false;
         }
         else        
         return true;
       }

       if(i == 0 && i2 == 2)  // Checks Commissioned worker
       {
         if(tf[0].getText()  == null || tf[0].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("First Name field is empty"); 
           tf[0].getTextField().requestFocus();
           return false;
         }
         else if(tf[1].getText()  == null || tf[1].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("Last Name field is empty");  
           tf[1].getTextField().requestFocus();  
           return false;
         }
         else if(tf[2].getText()  == null || tf[2].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("Employee ID field is empty"); 
           tf[2].getTextField().requestFocus(); 
           return false;
         }       
         else      
         return true;
       }

       if(i == 6 && i2 == 7)  // Checks Commissioned second time
       {
         if(tf[6].getText()  == null || tf[6].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("(c1)Commissioned: Rate field is empty"); 
           tf[0].getTextField().requestFocus();
           return false;
         }
         else if(tf[7].getText()  == null || tf[7].getText().length() == 0)
         {
           showStatus("(c2)Commissioned: Ratefield is empty");  
           tf[1].getTextField().requestFocus();  
           return false;
         }     
         else       
         return true;
       } 
       return false;

      }


     private boolean fieldsEmpty(int i, int i2, String[] a)
     {
       if(i == 4 && i2 == 7) // checks salaried
       { 
         for (int index = 4; index <= 7; index++)
         {
           if(tf[index].getText().length() != 0)
           {
            showStatus( a[index] + " should be empty");  //  Diplays error message in status area
            tf[index].getTextField().requestFocus();  //  Places focus in JTextField
            return true;
           }
           else return false;
         } // end for
       }  // end if

       if (i == 3 && i2 == 3) // checks hourly first time
       {
         if(tf[3].getText().length() != 0)
         {
          showStatus(a[3] + " field should be empty");  
          tf[3].getTextField().requestFocus();  
          return true;
         }
       } // end if

       if(i == 6 && i2 == 7) // checks hourly second time
       {      
         for (int index = 6; index <= 7; index++)
         {
           if(tf[index].getText().length() != 0)
           {
            showStatus(a[index] + " field should be empty"); 
            tf[index].getTextField().requestFocus();  
            return true;
           }

         } // end for
       }  // end if

       if(i == 3 && i2 == 5) // checks commissioned  
       {      
         for (int index = 3; index <= 5; index++)
         {
           if(tf[index].getText().length() != 0)
           {
            showStatus(a[index] + " field should be empty"); 
            tf[index].getTextField().requestFocus();  
            return true;
           }

         } // end for
       }  // end if

       return false;
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
       showStatus("");

       if (e.getSource() == cl)  //  Executes clear button is clicked
       {
         for (int i = 0; i < FIELDS; i++)
         {
           tf[i].getTextField().setText("");
           tf[0].getTextField().requestFocus(); 
         }
        }  //  End clear if    

       if (e.getSource() != cl)  
       {

         if(e.getSource() == sd)  // checks for salaried employee
         {
           showStatus("Salaried");
           fieldsExist(0,3);  
           fieldsEmpty(4,7, s);
           ta.append("lol");  
         }  // end salaried

         if(e.getSource() == hr)  // checks for hourly employee
         {
           showStatus("Hourly");
           fieldsExist(0,2);  
           fieldsExist(4,5);  
           fieldsEmpty(3,3, s);  
           fieldsEmpty(6,7, s);  
         }  // end hourly

         if(e.getSource() == cm)  // checks for commissioned employee
         {
           showStatus("Commissioned");
           fieldsExist(0,2);  
           fieldsExist(6,7);  
           fieldsEmpty(3,5, s);  
         }  // end commisssioned   
       } // end if
     }  // End of actionPerformed

}
```

and this is the Person class

```
public abstract class Person  
{
  private int i;  // private instance variables

  public Person(int i)  // one constructor
  {


  }




  public String toString() {return ??? ;}  // toString method

}
```

Comment: FIelds from other classes really don't belong in Person's toString.  The whole point of the toString method is that it shows what is stored in the object you're calling it on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Person class needs String variables like firstName and lastName. This is what I would use for my person class:

```
public class Person extends EmployeesApplet {
    private int i;  // private instance variables
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(int i)  // one constructor
    {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
    }

    public String getFirstName() 
    {
         return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) 
    {
         this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() 
    {
         return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) 
    {
         this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return getfirstName() + " " + getLastName();
    }  // toString method

}
```

Comment: How would i call the Person class toString in EmployeesApplet to update the JTextArea?